# Hot to handle async props in vue 3 composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Parent compoment:

```
const { getGroup, removePubli, removeTablet, loadTotal, error } = useGroups();
```

```
const group = ref({});
```

```
getGroup(group_id).then((g) => {
  group.value = g;
});
```

Child component:

```
const { group } = defineProps({
  group: {
    type: Object,
    default: {},
  },
});
```

Given the prop above, which is fetched by an async axios call, when I try to use it in a chield component it is undefined or a promise.

I've already tried to put an async inside onMounted hook but it doesn't work.

getGroup does it:

```
const getGroup = async (id) => {
  const r = await api.get(`/api/v1/groups/${id}`);
  if (r?.status !== 200) error.value = "Falhou";
  return r.data;
};
```

I want to await it before the code continues or find a way to do something when the promise resolves itself.

Comment: Normally `group` state is local to useGroups composable and getGroup modifies it. Don't render a component that depends on this data until it's available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in your code any `await`. Use await instead of `.then`!

```html
<script setup>
const { getGroup, removePubli, removeTablet, loadTotal, error } = useGroups();

const group = ref({})

const result = await getGroup(someId)

group.value = result.data // or what ever
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like it works but now it doesn 't render the page anymore. I'm trying to debug. Not any console errors.

Comment: @LucasVale So accept working answer as correct. And give vote up.

Comment: I'll do, but it now complains that component tree has not Suspense in its parente, but, its parente is the router-view. Any thoughts ?

Comment: I got this working, I had to put a suspense around the router-vue with a fallback. Thank you Bro.